# Increase the size of checkbox/radio buttons on hover CSS

Tags: css, checkbox, radio-button, hover

I am trying to make a visually accessible theme and want to increase the size of checkbox/radio buttons on `hover` with CSS

I have tried many things and none of them work, here is an example

```
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] + label span:hover {
    width: 40px !important;
    height: 40px !important; 
}
```

Here is the page I am working on
https://sum-app.net/members/Ubb3K1alaMRloph_-7eI0w/survey

Thanks for any assistance with this

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Note that the selector used in that CSS code selects a hovered `span`, which is a  descendent of a label that is a sibling of a checkbox which is a descendent of an element with the class "checkbox". So the element which ultimately becomes 40px x 40px is a `span` within a `label`, not a checkbox...

Comment: Hi, there is no span in the code I saw in the link you provided. And you probably want to allow the user to hover anywhere within div.checkbox and scale the whole thing up so it's easily seen as this is an accessibility issue so try .checkbox:hover { transform: scale(1.5); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```css
input[type=checkbox]:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(2); /* IE */
  -moz-transform: scale(2); /* FF */
  -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform: scale(2); /* Opera */
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
  <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Note that you can provide a working example without depending on an external site by using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) so that the user doesn't have to go elsewhere to see the CSS in action. Also, there's no need for the vendor prefixes any more (including IE since version 10).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for the recommendation. I couldn't get it working without vender prefixes, but did get the Snippet working